# I am getting an error Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'. while using openrowset function on dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: t-sql, azure-functions, azure-synapse, openrowset

First I added a credential:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Mumbai@1234';
GO
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credanubhav -- this name must match the container path, start with https and must not contain a trailing forward slash.
    WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE' -- this is a mandatory string and do not change it.
    , SECRET = '?{REDACTED}' -- this is the shared access signature token
GO
```

Then I Created an External Data Source:

```
    create external DATA SOURCE anubhav
    WITH(
        LOCATION = 'abfss://adls-container-1998@adlsaccount1998.dfs.core.windows.net/Folder1/',
CREDENTIAL=credanubhav
    )
```

(In my CSV file there is 3 columns name id, name and age) when I write openrowset function to see my data I am getting an error:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'blob.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE= 'anubhav',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74873217/i-am-getting-an-error-incorrect-syntax-near-openrowset-while-using-openrowset) questions. If you need to improve your question, there is an edit feature.

Comment: Okay Thanks do you know the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Currently OPENROWSET only works in a Synapse Serverless SQL pool, not a Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool. Instead you can use the [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true&tabs=dedicated#syntax-2) or the [COPY INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) statements.

For example try:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT ff_CSV
 WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
 FORMAT_OPTIONS(
 FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
 STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
 FIRST_ROW = 2,
 USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = True,
 Encoding = 'UTF8'
 )
 )


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[SampleExternal]
( [id] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
  [name] nvarchar(200) NULL,
  [age] nvarchar(200) NULL )
WITH
(
    LOCATION='blob.csv' ,
    DATA_SOURCE = anubhav ,
    FILE_FORMAT = ff_CSV ,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE ,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0
);

SELECT TOP 100 * from dbo.SampleExternal
```

Comment: I came to post this once I realized the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to let Synapse generate the code for you and then you can compare and know what is not different . For this you will hav to add the container as a linked service and then just point to the folder/file and Synapse Studio will do the rest .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop#create-external-data-source) and OPENROWSET use the *https* format, not *abfss*.

Sample:
https://<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net//subfolders

**NOTE**: This is NOT the answer - Dedicated SQL Pool does not support OPENROWSET.

Comment: We use https: format while using serverless SQL Pool. Still i have tried but getting the same error

Comment: You may need to add CREDENTIALS to your data source.

Comment: I have added the CREDENTIALS still having the same issue.